# Enable anonymous posting in bbPress (remove name, url, and email fields)?

Tags: wordpress, privacy, spam-prevention, bbpress

How can I completely hide and disable the name, url, and email fields in the "reply" a.k.a. comment form in bbPress so that users can participate anonymous in discussions without registering?

There is an [excellent thread on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131550/how-do-i-set-up-real-anonymous-posting-in-bbpress-forums) but it was closed for being off-topic (third party plugins).

Also keep in mind this functionality is different than in [WordPress Core](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/408825/how-to-hide-and-disable-url-and-email-fields-from-comments).

I want to not only hide the fields in HTML, but also disable/disallow them so that spam bots also cannot use them.

Answer (score 0):

This took a lot of research because of some [inaccurate suggestions](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/remove-e-mail-field-from-form-anonymous/) I found on bbpress.org. Incredibly, an old answer on [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131550/how-do-i-set-up-real-anonymous-posting-in-bbpress-forums) from several years ago had a solution that still (mostly) works.

However, that solution only enables anonymous comments but does not actually hide the name, url, and email fields, so I had to add a bit more code...

Additionally, I wanted a function that could auto-generate random "names" for the users, so that at least some basic reference points  existed in the discussions (e.g. *Hey @Larry, I disagree with you*) instead of having every single comment belonging to a user named "Anonymous" or whatever.

This fix is what I [came up with](https://gist.github.com/jessuppi/0663069e94af7f397510990ccd576a30) but it's buggy and still a work in progress... I'm posting this answer now to avoid losing the draft I started to write here.

I will be coming back to update this answer during the next several days.